# Medical image preprocessing for text elimination from images

Tags: python

I have a large dataset of xray images. These images contain texts on them.
The question is how could I remove the text from these image without loosing any information using python/opencv?

Please note that I will use these data to train a CNN model

An example of the image:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the images all the same size, with the text in the same position? Or do you need to do text detection and removal?

Comment: The text in different positions
yes, i want to do text detection and removal

Comment: Could you share a full-res image? Your sample is very low-res and something that can remove text from that will not work so well on the original. There seem to be some symbols in the top-right as well, I guess you want those removed too?

Comment: I tried to upload the full resolution image but the max size of uploaded i,age is 2 m so i couldn't upload it. i want to remove all the text from the image . Hope you could help me

Comment: Perhaps crop out a smaller area containing the text, or upload the full image to a file sharing service.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've researched, the best choice is to use the [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html), in particular, the method called "inpainting".
I hope it helps you, and please let me know if you have any other progress other than that.

See more info here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

PS The point here is that you should have a mask.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.